# 301 redirects php to html

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have had a look around and cant seem to find an answer for my question.

I have a .htaccess file where I have listed all my 301 redirects for the website www.rubbusa.com

The file has been uploaded with no errors but only the PDF files are redirecting, the php files are not.

Can PHP file not be redirected using a .htaccess file? or is it written in a certain way?

I did read that you can add a line of redirect code in a php page but these pages do not exist anymore.

Please see below a little sample of the .htaccess file

Thank you all for your support.

Michael

```
DirectoryIndex index.html.var index.htm index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml default.htm default.html home.htm index.php5 Default.html Default.htm home.html
RewriteEngine On


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^rubbusa.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.rubbusa.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.htm
Redirect 301 /brochures/Aviation-brochure.pdf http://www.rubbusa.com/brochures/aviation.pdf
Redirect 301 /brochures/Emergency-relief-brochure.pdf http://www.rubbusa.com/brochures/emergency_shelters.pdf
Redirect 301 /brochures/Environmental-brochure.pdf http://www.rubbusa.com/brochures/waste_recycling.pdf

Redirect 301 /bulk-storage-buildings/highlights.php http://www.rubbusa.com/markets/bulk-storage-buildings.htm
Redirect 301 /bulk-storage-buildings/photo-gallery.php http://www.rubbusa.com/photogallery/storage.htm
Redirect 301 /bulk-storage-buildings/projects.php http://www.rubbusa.com/markets/bulk-storage-buildings.htm
```

Comment: add the content of your .htaccess file.

Comment: Do you have other rules? Because it looks like something else is handling the request

Comment: Hello thank you for getting back to me. As far as i know i dont have any other rules in place. Should this technique of redirecting working on php files ?

Answer (score 0):

To 301 redirect from a .php file you need to send the correct headers:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com");
?>
```